# Which machine learning/AI method is this problem related to?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining

I am new to machine learning and AI, and I am working on a problem in which I need to clean a table (database) of text/words. For example I should delete words like and, the, etc. , or replace words like COMP with company or substitute other acronyms with the suitable words. I wanted to find some resources on the techniques proposed for this purpose and to find what else I can do to better clean the table. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may do cleaning/substitution with grep-like tools in R, Python, or GNU Linux. No need in ML/AI tools.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thanks, I will try that. but  I also want to understand the algorithms that are used for this purpose.

Comment: Why do you need to clean the table? (By the way: Your table gets the cleanest with `TRUNCATE TABLE` ;-))

Answer (score 1):

> For example I should delete words like and, the, etc. ...

In natural language processing, this first task is called [stop word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) removal. You can identify them by looking at the [words' frequency over the documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf); uninformative words appear very often.

Comment: thanks, what other topics should I look into other than stop word removal?

Comment: Look up "preprocessing". Tokenization, stemming, lemmatization.